# Adding @specialized tag causes "value is not a member" error in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following class definition for a resizable array in Scala:

```
class ResizeableArray[T: Manifest](initialCapacity: Int) {
  private var capacity = initialCapacity
  private var arr = Array.ofDim[T](capacity)
}
```

This definition works fine, but when I add `@specialized(Int)` to specialize for primitive type `Int`, I get the following strange error:

```
class ResizeableArray[@specialized(Int) T: Manifest](initialCapacity: Int) {
  private var capacity = initialCapacity
  private var arr = Array.ofDim[T](capacity)
}

<console>:15: error: value capacity is not a member of ResizeableArray$mcI$sp
         private var arr = Array.ofDim[T](capacity)
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on here? I am using Scala 2.12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Specialized SID Section 3.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/sids/dragos/Thu,%202010-05-06,%2017:56/sid-spec.pdf):

> Not all members of a class are specialized. Currently, specialized variants of
>   a member m are created only when m’s type contains at least one specialized
>   naked type parameter, or an array of a naked specialized type parameter.

Normally, this might not make a difference, but it does here. This is because when you specialize `ResizeableArray` for `Int`, the compiler generates another class like this (note that `var capacity` isn't there):

```
  <specialized> class ResizeableArray$mcI$sp extends ResizeableArray {
    implicit <paramaccessor> private val evidence$1: scala.reflect.Manifest = _;
    <specialized> protected[this] var arr$mcI$sp: Array[Int] = _;
    <accessor> <specialized> protected def arr$mcI$sp(): Array[Int] = ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.this.arr$mcI$sp;
    override <accessor> <specialized> protected def arr(): Array[Int] = ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.this.arr$mcI$sp();
    <accessor> <specialized> protected def arr$mcI$sp_=(x$1: Array[Int]): Unit = ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.this.arr$mcI$sp = x$1;
    override <accessor> <specialized> protected def arr_=(x$1: Array[Int]): Unit = ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.this.arr$mcI$sp_=(x$1);
    def specInstance$(): Boolean = true;
    override <bridge> <specialized> <artifact> protected def arr_=(x$1: Object): Unit = ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.this.arr_=(x$1.$asInstanceOf[Array[Int]]());
    override <bridge> <specialized> <artifact> protected def arr(): Object = ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.this.arr();
    <specialized> def <init>(initialCapacity: Int, evidence$1: scala.reflect.Manifest): ResizeableArray$mcI$sp = {
      ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.this.evidence$1 = evidence$1;
      ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.super.<init>(initialCapacity, evidence$1);
      ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.this.arr$mcI$sp = scala.Array.ofDim(ResizeableArray$mcI$sp.this.initialCapacity(), evidence$1).$asInstanceOf[Array[Int]]();
      ()
    }
  }
```

By the above definition, only members that contain the specialized parameter in some way will be overridden in the implementation of `ResizeableArray$mcI$sp`. This means that `capacity` will not be overridden or implemented in the specialized class, so the compiler expects that it will be inherited instead, if needed. Unfortunately, since `capacity` is private, it is not inherited and you get a compiler error. I don't know if private members were overlooked here or consciously excluded, but you will need to take care when using them in specialzed classes.

In this case, a simple work-around will do:

```
class ResizeableArray[@specialized(Int) T: Manifest](initialCapacity: Int) {
  private var capacity = initialCapacity
  private var arr = Array.ofDim[T](initialCapacity)
}
```

The only other way around this would be to make `capacity` public, which surely you wouldn't want here, but may be acceptable in other cases (when it isn't mutable).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a generic class and you use the @specialized annotation,the compiler will actually generate two versions of the class: the normal, generic one, in which the type parameter is erased, and a special subclass. In your case, the problem happens only in `$mcI$sp` method of Scala specific class.  I just tried it by removing private and the error disappeared.

```
class ResizeableArray[@specialized(Int) T: Manifest](initialCapacity: Int) {
 var capacity = initialCapacity
  private var arr = Array.ofDim[T](capacity)
}
```

I'm not very sure, this problem is with variable scope.

**Note** Array is not @specialized

Comment: I also noticed that by removing private, the error message disappears, but cannot figure out why. You say that array is not specialized, you mean that for the primitive variant I do not get the Java equivalent of int[capacity] and it will still be Object[capacity]?